# Postgis ST_AsMVT() return missing libprotobuf-c on MacOSX High Sierra

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, postgis, protobuf-c, vector-tiles

I try to get MVT format from my geometry table with this query

```
SELECT ST_AsMVT(q)
FROM (
        SELECT
                id_kelurahan,
                nama_kelurahan,
                ST_AsMVTGeom(
                        feature,
                        TileBBox(11, 1150, 1724, 3857),
                        4096,
                        0,
                        false
                ) geom
        FROM kelurahan
        WHERE ST_Intersects(feature, (SELECT ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(22.1484375, -76.72022329036133, 22.32421875, -76.6797849031069, 4326), 3857)))
) q
```

As you can see I using Postgis extension function `ST_AsMVT()` to convert my inner query result to MVT but instead of getting the expected result (MVT) it genereate the missing libprotobuf-c error.
I'm on MacOSX High Sierra 10.13.1, Postgis version 2.4.0.

I already research the error and try some of it solutions

```
brew install protobuf
brew install protobuf-c
```

both of the process ends succesfully with no error. already restart my device but the `missing libprotobuf-c` error still occured.

Comment: Try to install libprotobuf-c-dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install postgis with this command:

`brew install postgis --with-protobuf-c`

I've encountered this problem last time and this fixed it on mac high sierra.

Comment: Can you explain why this is a solution to the issue? Maybe `postgis` is required for something and OP may not realize it? etc. etc.

Comment: PostGIS makes sure that you first have it installed when using the `ST_AsMVT()` function and it needs to check that you have installed protobuf-c and its version.

Comment: I uninstall both postgis extension and postgresql on my machine and re-run the postgis installation using this command, reboot my device and it works. thank you for your response.

Comment: You can't just install protobuf-c, postgis needs to be compiled with that support available at compile time

Comment: Brew has removed options from its formulae https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/36286/files This solution is no longer valid

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstall postgis:

```
brew reinstall postgis --with-protobuf-c
```